# Wordpress Elementor script inside html "Server Error"

Tags: html, wordpress, elementor, surveymonkey

To embed my surveymonkey on my website I received the script code and copied it inside an html section. I placed this html section with Elementor at the center of the page.

```
<script>(function(t,e,s,n){var o,a,c;t.SMCX=t.SMCX||[],e.getElementById(n)||(o=e.getElementsByTagName(s),a=o[o.length-1],c=e.createElement(s),c.type="text/javascript",c.async=!0,c.id=n,c.src="https://widget.surveymonkey.com/collect/website/js/<TokenToMySurvey>.js",a.parentNode.insertBefore(c,a))})(window,document,"script","smcx-sdk");</script>
```

Now I face to issues. First, the survey is displayed in the preview but at the bottom of the page. Second, as I hit "Save" or "Publish" I get

`Server Error (510 No Reason Phrase)`

How do I put the script part correctly inside the html?

Comment: Do you have Wordfence or any other security plugin installed?

Comment: @ozgur No I don't.

Comment: sometimes security plugins block direct script injections into the page content. I thought a problem might have arised in that context. Maybe there is a conflict with elementor's internal variables or functions. I suggested an answer below that turns your script code into a shortcode which then can be added into elementor directly with elementor's shortode widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create a shortcode by adding the code below to your theme's functions.php (Preferably into your child theme's functions.php)

I made up the shortcode name `fiscblogsurvey` and function name. You can call them whatever you want.

```
// function that runs when shortcode is called
function fiscblog_shortcode() { 
    return '<script>(function(t,e,s,n){var o,a,c;t.SMCX=t.SMCX||[],e.getElementById(n)||(o=e.getElementsByTagName(s),a=o[o.length-1],c=e.createElement(s),c.type="text/javascript",c.async=!0,c.id=n,c.src="https://widget.surveymonkey.com/collect/website/js/<TokenToMySurvey>.js",a.parentNode.insertBefore(c,a))})(window,document,"script","smcx-sdk");</script>';
} 
// register shortcode
add_shortcode('fiscblogsurvey', 'fiscblog_shortcode');
```

You can now add this `shortcode` into elementor using elementor's shortcode widget by typing inside `[fiscblogsurvey]`

Comment: Where do I find said `functions.php` file?

Comment: it is inside your theme's main folder.  /wp-content/themes/[the name of your theme]

Comment: This filesyste is accessible from the hosting service?

Comment: Yes, it is accessible via File Manager of your control panel. Alternatively, you can install Code Snippets plugin and add the snippet via this plug. https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/